# .Net Standard project dependencies

Tags: .net-standard

After compilation of some project I have only "project.dll" file within "Release" folder. Where is all dependencies? How can I deploy them to "Release" folder?

Comment: There's a "Copy Local" setting in the "Properties" pane of each project.  However, I suspect you have a different problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean that "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" is missing for example

Comment: In your References in the Solutions Explorer, you can click on the Newtonsoft.json reference, go to the Properties tab, and the Copy Local setting is there as well.  But that should already be happening automatically, if you're using Nuget to get Newtonsoft.json.

Answer (score 0):

In order to publish all the files you should run

```
dotnet publish
```

That should make sure you have all the dependencies in a single location.